# oauth2client.client.AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant

Tags: python, gspread

I've a Python script on a server, which runs every day at morning, and syncing rows from several databases to a Google Spreadsheet. This script runs till May of 2016 on *that* server without any problem, and runs an another one too since older. The scripts are equals and use same JSON credentials files.
A few days ago, on that server I've got this error message:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gspread/client.py", line 326, in authorize
  client.login()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gspread/client.py", line 85, in login
  self.auth.refresh(http)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 516, in refresh
  self._refresh(http.request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 653, in _refresh
  self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 710, in _do_refresh_request
  raise AccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg)
oauth2client.client.AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant
```

But (as I wrote) the same script runs without problem on another server. The two scripts uses different spreadsheets, but all of them had permissions for the service user. There isn't any changes in documents shared, permissions, etc. Both server has same script and json credential file, but the mentioned server asserts this message. That scripts had worked about 3 months. No changes in code, nor permissions.

What would be the problem?

Thanks,
a.

Comment: How long does the script run for generally?

Comment: It runs between 5 and 20 minutes. But - of course - now it takes about few seconds.

Comment: Well, I don't know how and why, but today morning the script ran successfully again... I didn't do anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue was most probably caused due to a wrong server time synchronizaton.

Next time, try to sync your server time to Network Time Servers by, for example, installing **ntp**.

That should solve the issue.

Comment: No - there were (and are) ntp installes on both server. Anyway, the problem had solved, but I don't know, why ahd how. See my previous comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355881/oauth2client-client-accesstokenrefresherror-invalid-grant/43111516#comment-67064708. Regards, a.

Comment: I apologize, you're right - the problem occured again today, and I've checked the server time. Now I realized, that the ntp was set up incorrectly. Many thanks for your help!